# Oracle Linux - Sudo Permission for my group expire after a day

Tags: linux, rhel, sudo, oracle-linux, quest-privilege-access

On Oracle Linux, I have been given sudo permission to root for my group. But the permissions expire the next day when i login and try to access root commands. I checked the sudoers file there is no "Defaults timestamp_timeout=0" entry exists. The same access works for other group for unlimited days. We are using sudo policy on QAS. Can you give the command to add group to sudoers file.

Can you shed some light on this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Typically this behavior indicates the `sudoers` file is under control of some centralized management system (Puppet, Salt, etc.). If you're unaware of the management system, you might make some changes manually. That may work for a while... until the management system runs a check and rolls back your changes.

The `timestamp_timeout` parameter in the sudoers file affects how often you must enter your password when using sudo. It doesn't cause the actual sudo permission to expire - it just determines how often sudo must verify that the person at the keyboard is actually the authorized user.